# Add css class onClick with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Someone help me how to add **css** class with **jquery**? I've bootstrap tab content with the current class have a class "`active`".

```
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane **active**" id="one">
      <div class="row">
```

and my other tab code is:

```
    <div class="tab-pane" id="two">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
```

if i click a tab with `id` two, i want to add `active` class on `class="tab-pane"`.

Comment: use (".tab-pane").addClass("active")

Comment: bootstrap has that add active class for tab.

Comment: can you explain a full script implementation

Comment: If you use Bootstrap it should to that itself without having to do it from scratch. Maybe you're missing something. Have you included Bootstrap libraries correctly?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work but boostrap already has it.

```
$(".tab-pane").click(function(){
      $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active"); //to remove active class from other tabs
      $("this").addClass("active"); //to add active class to clicked tab
    });
```

Comment: thank it's work for me, but my problem is not done anymore i think i've wrong idea, anyway thank for the script it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `click` function.

```
$(".tab-pane").click(function(){
      $(".tab-pane").attr("class","tab-pane active"); //add whatever class you want to. In this case, `active`is added. 

    });
```