# In nested lists, change style of individual <li> elements when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, sory for my English and apologize for my bad explanation of the problem (this is my first question on stackoverflow). I will try to explain the problem a little better:

I have nested lists of elements (steps to do something) generated dynamically (in the visual editor of WordPress posts). I want that when I click on any element (step) of the list, this element is highlighted with a background. The goal does not seem too difficult, and I thought that this code should work:

```js
$('li').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('highlight'); //Alternate hihglight on click
   $('.highlight').not(this).removeClass('highlight'); //Remove any other highlight. 
});
```

```css
.highlight{background:#ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3
        <ol>
            <li>Element 3.1</li>
            <li>Element 3.2
                <ol>
                    <li>Element 3.2.1</li>
                    <li>Element 3.2.2</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
 </li>
    <li>Element 4
        <ol>
            <li>Element 4.1</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Element 5</li>
</ol>
```

But when I click on a parent element (e.g. Element 3) or I click on a child element (e.g. Element 3.1 or Element 3.2.2) the entire nested list is highlighted and not only the clicked element.

Thanks for all the previous answers (Pointy, Chris-Developer and Dave) but they don't solve th problem completely (you can try in the code snippet).

Maybe a possible solution could be to add a "span" surrounding the text of each element using JavaScript (remember that the list is generated by a visual editor) when the document is loaded, and then the previous jQuery code (with minor modifications) could work. I will try. Any other solutions or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Add a rule for `ol`: `ol { background-color: white; }` (or whatever color you want)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add css class onClick with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850455/add-css-class-onclick-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple things that I think you can do to fix the problem:

1. Add a style rule to force a consistent solid background for the `<ol>` blocks;
2. When you handle a "click", stop event propagation so that the *parent* `<li>` doesn't also respond.

The first one is simple:

```
ol { background-color: white; }
```

And so is the second:

```
$('li').click(function(e){
     $(this).toggleClass('my_li_background'); //Alternate background on click
     $('.my_li_background').not(this).removeClass('my_li_background'); //Remove other active backgrounds (optional)
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem only happens when clicking on children. When you click on an li that is a child of an li, the click sort of "happens on both" (child first, then parent) since one li is inside another. To stop the click from propagating through to the parent, use stopImmediatePropogation():

```
$('li').click(function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  $(this).toggleClass('my_li_background'); //Alternate background on click
  $('.my_li_background').not(this).removeClass('my_li_background'); //Remove other active backgrounds (optional)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this using CSS by adding an id=" " to each  tag, example of HTML:

```css
li#parent:active {
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li id="parent">Element 1</li>
   <li>Element 2</li>
   <li>Element 3</li>
      <ol>
         <li id="parent">Element 3.1</li>
         <li>Elenent 3.2</li>
            <ol>
               <li id="parent">Element 3.2.1</li>
               <li>Element 3.2.2</li>
            </ol>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

What you're looking to do can be achieved without the use of JavaScript.

Hope this helps!